# Como simular o click de um botão com httpWebRequest

Tags: c#, http

Esse codigo meu pega todo um conteudo especifico de um site
Como simular o click de um botão?

```
[Route("HomeController/Requisicao")] // Matches 'Products/Index'
            public string Requisicao()
            {
                var result = "";
                string path = "http://testedev-rpa.ddns.net";
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {


                    streamWriter.Write(true);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();

                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                }

                return result;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço algo parecido utilizando o WebBrowser para pegar um elemento de um HTML e invocar o click do mesmo. Exemplo:

```
var botao = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("id_do_botao");
botao?.InvokeMember("click");
```

Verifique se você consegue pegar o HTML que é retornado para você e passá-lo para um WebBrowser.

Comment: Pois é, estou usando selenium para isso, porém está me dando um erro do path do eviroment dele, mesmo eu fazendo download do driver do chrome